# trying to create an infinite series of prime numbers in an efficient way

Tags: python, math, primes

Theory: If any number, suppose X, is not divisible by prime numbers which are less than X, then X is also a prime number.

```
prime = 5
list_of_prime  = [2 , 3]

for int in list_of_prime:
    if prime % int == 0:
        pass

    else:
        print(prime)
        list_of_prime.append(prime)
    prime += 1
```

The problem is when I try to run above code, instead of generating an infinite list of prime number it generates only arithmetic series of difference 1.

I am trying to solve this from 3 days.
I tried making a list of prime numbers  which are less than 5, i.e. 2,3
What my code is supposed to do is test if prime_no = 5 is divisible by others prime numbers which are less then 5 i.e. 2, 3
Since 5 is not divisible by any of them, prime_no = 5 is added to list of prime numbers.
Then prime_no = 5 is increased by 1 to 6 and above process repeats itself.

Comment: Print your ``list_of_prime`` in every iteration and you'll see what's happenning here. You must check ``prime % int`` for ALL numbers of the list before appending to list.

Comment: could you please elaborate? I am very new to understand your language and I also don't know English well

Comment: Demo showing the problems with your code using `print()` statements as basic debugging, plus a fix to your code and two optimisations to that fix: https://trinket.io/python3/9c7b3feba4

Comment: You don't need to check all primes less than 5, you want factors less than the square root of 5. Any factor larger than the square root of 5 will have to be multiplied with a factor smaller than the square root of 5, which you'll have already checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- it is always checking the current prime number with only the last element added to list_of_prime once you don't restart the list iteration when you append a new element
- it is considering your number as prime in the first division verification. As you said, it must verify that it can't be divided by any previous prime number to consider it another prime.

Check the code below with my suggestion:

```
number = 5
list_of_prime = [2, 3]

while True:
    for prime in list_of_prime:
        if number % prime == 0:
            break
        if prime == list_of_prime[-1]:
            list_of_prime.append(number)

    number += 1
```

A tip would be to try solve the prime number verification for X first and finally, if you want to iterate it infinitely, just put the code inside an infinite loop.

Feel free to ask if you have any question.

UPDATED

Actually, there was a typo and I left a "i" variable where should be "prime".

Comment: If you're going to fix the OP's code, I'd also add that there's no need to check for factors above the square-root of the number being tested.  That massively cuts down on the number of iterations per value being tested.

Comment: Since it's stopping iteration for current number when the first valid multiple is found, I guess there is no need to verify it. If you could bring a case that is not satisfied I'd glad update the code.

Comment: When testing if `51` is prime, your code checks the factors `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]` and concludes that it is prime.  It can, however, be concluded that it is prime just by checking `[2, 3, 5, 7]`

Comment: Demo showing four approaches yours being the slowest by a ***long*** way, but with two tweaks *(`+=2` and stopping at `sqrt`)* it becomes the fastest.  https://trinket.io/python3/aef95067ad

Comment: This code: 1) Definitely doesn't work (you're testing against `i`, which is not a declared variable anywhere), and 2) Is useless even if it works (because the outer loop *never* terminates, and the results just collect in a continuously expanding `list` no one will ever see). I'd suggest: 1) Making it actually work, and 2) Refactoring it into a generator function (using `yield`/`yield from`) so that an outside caller could iterate over the result of a call, use the values as they're produced, and potentially `break` when they're done.

Comment: Example of generator function moderately optimized (to avoid checking even numbers entirely, and only check for factors up to the square root of the number being tested): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHRTsMwDHzvV1hCSA2qprG9IKR9BY8IoTRxmbUmDokH2teXtknZivBbzuc7@xIucmS/fwpxGMgFjgJOy7HqIjsgwSjMfYLSMnz20lDqyWCmtJTQyNLPr6qy2MEH@vcQyWGq1XMFY10Iews7gDt4CWhI92B0whERhqS/EL45nmYqW1uG4QCvbzPWcQR/di1GIJ9XqfcN7Ir6QpnHJkZes75KNWW/FTRdu6H0GaXO4krdCE5FHXiWxfo@G6wpU7UR9ekXxT794VxNNzoE9HbxW7FyRrkz/P8JJf5RawzgoVx5m3bzuN0qNfwA) Takes about 40 ms to generate first 10K primes on my laptop.